# ABAP OLE - Open excel password protected workbook

Tags: ole, abap

I'm trying to open a password protected excel file using SAP ABAP OLE OBJECT as follows:

```
DATA: lt_excel_line(4096) OCCURS 10 WITH HEADER LINE.
DATA: app       TYPE ole2_object,
      workbook  TYPE ole2_object,
      worksheet TYPE ole2_object.

CREATE OBJECT app 'EXCEL.APPLICATION'.
SET PROPERTY OF app 'VISIBLE' = 0.

CALL METHOD OF app 'WORKBOOKS' = workbook.

CALL METHOD OF workbook 'OPEN'
  EXPORTING
  #1 = '<filename>'
  #5 = '<password>'.
```

The filename and password are definitely correct and the following VBA code opens the file as required no problem:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open Filename:="<filename>", Password:="<password>")
```

But the ABAP code always returns sy-subrc = 2. Anyone know what could be going on? Or what else I can try? Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the parameters being positional only (just a guess), as the SAP GUI automation does not support parameter names. There are 3 parameters between `Filename` and `Password`, so you numbered them correctly, but I guess the SAP GUI automation controller does not see it that way.

I replicated your problem and got it working as follows:

```
CALL METHOD OF workbook 'OPEN' = document
  EXPORTING
  #1 = '<filename>'
  #2 = 0              "UpdateLinks
  #3 = 0              "ReadOnly
  #4 = 1              "Format
  #5 = '<password>'.
```

Here I am explicitly passing the parameters `UpdateLinks`, `ReadOnly` and `Format`.

I tested it first in VBA. It seems `Format` (#4) must be set to true. I don't know what that does.

Remember to set the document handle as a return from this call as I do here, otherwise you don't have a reference to it!

Comment: Seems quirky that it doesn't recognise the position by number but this does work - thank you very much! Have marked solved